# How to edit a Comment value in Manatee.Trello?

Tags: c#, manatee.trello

I have a comment I would like to be able to modify but I am not sure how to process.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
using Manatee.Trello;

public class MyClass
{
     //identification is done beforehand as per Manatee.Trello's wiki
     Card c =  new Card(existingCardID);
     foreach(Action comment in card.Comments)
     {
         comment.Data.Value="empty comment";
     }
}
```

However, `Action.Data.Value` only has `get` capabilities. What is the correct way to update a comment data using this library?

Comment: I've updated my answer for you.  I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated!

```
action.Data.Text = "updated comment";
```

You'll likely get an error from Trello if the action isn't a comment.

I'll add a note in the wiki.  I realize it's a bit hidden.

### Edit... 2, I guess.

I've recently published Manatee.Trello v1.16.0 which resolves this bug.  Use it as indicated above.

Comment: You shouldn't post non-answers. You should delete this and repost as a comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity, technically it is an answer.  It is the only answer.  "You can't do what you want."

Comment: I tried your solution. It does compile, but at runtime, I get an error from Manatee.Trello : `ValidationException'1: 'someTextValue' is not a valid value. Manatee.Trello.ActionData.set_Text (System.String value)`

Comment: Please go to my github repo and create an issue.

Comment: Submited. Thanks for the work with this library btw. Despite this issue, it helped me a great lot :)

Comment: @Aserre I've updated my answer for you.  Thanks for the question.